# Can `msg.value` be trusted to remain the same after an external call?

Tags: solidity, security, payable, msg.value

Can `msg.value` be trusted to remain the same after the `weth.deposit` call in the `foo` function?

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.19;

interface WETHLike {
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256 balance);
    function deposit() external payable;
}

contract MsgValue {
    WETHLike public weth;

    function foo() external payable {
        uint256 initialBalance = weth.balanceOf(address(this));
        weth.deposit{ value: msg.value }();
        uint256 finalBalance = weth.balanceOf(address(this));
        uint256 creditAmount = finalBalance - initialBalance;
        if (creditAmount < msg.value) {
            revert("insufficient credit amount");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Every message call is encapsulated in its own context, any external message call made inside another context cannot modify that context in any way.

Members of `msg.` (msg.sender, msg.value, etc.) will always refer to the message call you're in, and is set by the previous caller and will stay constant for the whole message call (expect msg.gas, which would change over the call, obviously, and for consistency it was removed and replaced by `gasleft()` for that very reason),

members of `tx.` (tx.origin, tx.gasprice, etc.) refer to the whole transaction are set by the original sender of the transaction and stay constant for the whole transaction,

members of `block.` (block.timestamp, block.coinbase, etc.)  are set by the validator completing the block and are the same for every transaction in the block as well.